# Why is PostgreSQL complaining about syntax on this UPDATE statement?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a Python function that can take a dictionary, and UPDATE multiple fields of a row (given a primary key) in SQL.

```
def sql_update(conn, table, data, pkeyname, pkeyval):
    query = f"UPDATE {table} SET " + ', '.join(
        "{}=?".format(k) for k in data.keys()) + f" WHERE {pkeyname}=?"

    conn.execute(query, list(data.values()) + [pkeyval])
```

And I call it like so:

```
sqlite_update(CURSOR, 'students', {'last_name' : "gamgee"}, "student_id", "5")
```

The following generated SQL statement reports an invalid syntax:

```
UPDATE students SET last_name=? WHERE student_id=? ['gamgee', '5']

syntax error at or near "=?"
```

This statement works perfectly fine in SQLite, why does PostgreSQL complain? Is it not smart enough to replace with the statements in my array? If not, then how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want the query to do?

Comment: You don't specify which driver you are using, but perhaps it uses "%s" ather than "?" ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want the ? to be filled (in place) by the values in the array at the end, it's quite convenient

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm using psycopg2, but also this statement won't execute when I execute it in my Navicat query editor

Comment: I don't see this statement `UPDATE students SET last_name=? WHERE student_id=? ['gamgee', '5']` working in `sqlite3` either.  What driver are you using for `sqlite3` and where are you finding that statement? In the `psycopg2` case you will need to  use `%s` as placeholders(`%(name)s` for named parameters). For more information see [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write:

```
UPDATE students
    SET last_name = ?
    WHERE student_id = ANY (ARRAY['gamgee', '5']);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=527b8f69ed83eed4c884e6418c3cd6f2) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

Comment: That statement also seems to produce a syntax error

Comment: The statement inside that db<>fiddle you linked is not the same statement in your comment, which produes a syntax error before 'WHERE'

Comment: @Fleckenator . . . The first `?` is a parameter placeholder for a value.  I figured you know how to handle that if you are using `?` and have used parameters in SQLite.

Comment: Indeed the `?` is a placeholder for a value, however I do not understand why PostgreSQL does not accept it as a placeholder for a value

Comment: @Fleckenator . . . It does (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-commands.html).  You can also use a named parameter.